# Multiple tables with limited columns or Single table with multiple columns? which is better?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

This is my first time doing a bit of medium size project with laravel. I have an authentication system based on Sentinel package. As for my project requirements my users table became filled with so many columns like: first name, last name, email , address , country_code , description, rating, phone_number, company_name , and so on

What should I do? which is better? keep them all in one table? or separate this table into many tables?

Please when you answer me tell me the logic behind the answer you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you want to separate your table?
if you have many table , when you want select from your table , you need more join and this makes bad performance for your app.